# Android studio status bar out pf position

Tags: android-studio

The toolbar item that displays the current git branch/app running status is out of position. I tried restoring the layout, but it didn't change anything.

[image]

Comment: Try look into your git settings and make sure you push the commit.

Comment: @ThomasMorris couldn't find anything in git settings

Answer (score 1):

Toggling View->Appearance-> Status bar solved the issue